# nginx location with negation pattern

Tags: nginx

How to add a negation pattern to a location block?

I want to match all files named `*.js` but not files named `*-php.js`

This pattern will match all `*.js` files including `*-php.js`

```
location ~ \.js$ {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

> regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance

So you may simply put your "negation pattern" before:

```
location ~ -php\.js$ {
  deny all;
}

location ~ \.js$ {

}
```